# How to simply concatenate multiple tables horizontally in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, join, concatenation

I have three tables `A`, `B` and `C`. All three tables contain `ID1` and `ID2` columns (which have exact same values in same order) and some other columns say `A_x`, `B_x` and `C_x`, in `A`, `B` and `C` respectively.

Thus `A` contains `ID1`, `ID2`, and `A_x`, and so on.

I want to simply concatenate these three tables horizontally so that resulting table will contain columns `ID1`, `ID2`, `A_x`, `B_x` and `C_x`. Do I really need to take a join if I know that `ID1` and `ID2` are exactly same in these three tables?

Comment: Yes, it's join you need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    SELECT 
            a.ID1, b.ID2, a.x, b.x, c.x, < and so on >
    FROM 
            a JOIN b ON a.ID1=b.ID1 AND a.ID2=b.ID2
              JOIN c ON a.ID1=c.ID1 AND a.ID2=c.ID2
```